# What does Array.sort!{|element|Array.count(element)} does?

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

I wanted to sort some Strings in a array by the frequency they appear in the array. I know that i can use sort_by to achieve this but by chance I used this code *items.sort!{|x|items.count(x)}* and wanted to know what happened to the list.

```
items = ["apple", "pineapple", "apple", "apple", "orange", "orange", "grape"]
items.sort!{|x|items.count(x)}
items = ["grape", "apple", "apple", "orange", "apple", "orange", "pineapple"]

items = ["apple", "pineapple", "apple", "apple", "orange", "orange", "grape", "pineapple", "apple", "orange"]
items.sort!{|x|items.count(x)}
items = ["orange", "orange", "apple", "grape", "apple", "pineapple", "orange", "apple", "apple", "pineapple"]
```